# How to connect python program to a GUI interface

Tags: python, class, user-interface

I was wondering whether it is possible to connect already created python class to a gui interface with a button to obtain the data. I would like to create a window that will allow to write an input of "filename" and "share" variables for my class and button for get.data()
here is my code:

```
class Loan:
def __init__(self, filename, share=0):
   #read csv data
   self.data=pd.read_csv(filename)
   self.filename=filename
   self.data=self.data[['month','Probability','Payment', 'upb','current_interest_rate',
                         'delinquent_payment_count']]
  
   self.share= share
   
   

def get_prn_bal1(self, p1, UPB):
    return p1 * UPB

       
def get_int1(self, prn_bal1, current_interest_rate, month, DQ):
    return prn_bal1 * current_interest_rate/12 * (month+DQ+1)



def get_data(self):
    
    self.data['Principal1'] = self.data.apply(lambda x: self.get_prn_bal1(x['Probability'], x['upb']), axis=1)
    self.data['Interest1'] = self.data.apply(lambda x: self.get_int1(x['Principal1'],x['current_interest_rate'], 
                                                                             x['month'], x['delinquent_payment_count']), axis=1)
    
    
   
    f = open(self.filename,"w+")
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
    self.data.to_csv(self.filename, header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: You can look PySimpleGUI

Comment: Python is not yet mature on GUI front. I would suggest building simple GUI with help of Web App technology. Example `streamlit` or a browser experience, building simple site with Flask or FastAPI with good looking bootstrap pages.